# Wildfly Initialization: Time Delay causes IllegalStateException in Java-EE Application

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, wildfly, illegalstateexception

I have a simple java project which is fetching and calculating data called `CalculatorService`. It's included via buildpath within a JavaEE application which is deployed on a wildfly server.

When I run the wildfly server the database and its tables are going to be built. After that an `InitializationBean` is running where some data is fetched through a so called `CalculatorService`. Afterwards that data is going to be stored within the database. Lets take a look at the `InitializationBean` of the JavaEE applictaion.

```
@Singleton
@Startup
public class InitializationBean {

    @Inject
    private InitService initService;

    @PostConstruct
    private void initialize() {
        // Start CalculatorService and fetch data.
        CalculatorService calcService = new CalculatorService();
        calcService.fetchData();
        System.out.println("DONE <===========");
        initService.storeData();
    }
}
```

The `InitService` looks like:

```
@Singleton
public class InitService {

    @EJB
    private DataDAO dataDAO;

    public void storeData() {
        // Get fetched data stored within CalculatorService.
        Set <DataCalc> dataSet = CalculatorService.getAllData();
        // Loop through fetched data of CalculatorService and transform to valid entity.
        for (DataCalc d : dataSet) {
            Data data = new Data();
            data.setName(d.getName());
            try { // Store in database
                dataDAO.create(data);
            } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    }
    }
}
```

If I run the server with the setup above using test data and not the `CalculatorService` everything works as supposed to. But as soon as I use the service I get the following output:

```
DONE <===========
ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 88) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.subunit."MyProject.ear"."MyProject.jar".component.InitializationBean.START: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit."MyProject.ear"."MyProject.jar".component.InitializationBean.START: java.lang.IllegalStateException: WFLYEE0042: Failed to construct component instance
    at org.jboss.as.ee@14.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ee.component.ComponentStartService$1.run(ComponentStartService.java:57)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:514)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.2.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.2.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1985)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.2.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1487)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.2.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1378)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.2.Final//org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:485)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: WFLYEE0042: Failed to construct component instance
    at org.jboss.as.ee@14.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ee.component.BasicComponent.constructComponentInstance(BasicComponent.java:163)
    at org.jboss.as.ee@14.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ee.component.BasicComponent.constructComponentInstance(BasicComponent.java:134)
    at org.jboss.as.ee@14.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ee.component.BasicComponent.createInstance(BasicComponent.java:88)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3@14.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.singleton.SingletonComponent.getComponentInstance(SingletonComponent.java:127)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3@14.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.singleton.SingletonComponent.start(SingletonComponent.java:141)
    at org.jboss.as.ee@14.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ee.component.ComponentStartService$1.run(ComponentStartService.java:54)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at org.jboss.msc@1.4.3.Final//org.jboss.msc.value.InjectedValue.getValue(InjectedValue.java:50)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3@14.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.ModuleDeployment$ModuleDeploymentStartService$1.run(ModuleDeployment.java:102)
    at org.jboss.as.ee@14.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.StartupCountdown.countDown(StartupCountdown.java:27)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3@14.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.singleton.StartupCountDownInterceptor.processInvocation(StartupCountDownInterceptor.java:28)
    at org.jboss.invocation@1.5.1.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.invocation@1.5.1.Final//org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:53)
    at org.jboss.as.ee@14.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ee.component.BasicComponent.constructComponentInstance(BasicComponent.java:161)
    ... 13 more
```

Because the `CalculatorService` takes very long to process (more than two hours) I assume that it has something to do with time. But as there is nothing like a `TimeoutException` I have no idea where to start.

**UPDATE**

When the `CalculatorService` has to fetch just a little cut out of the data which takes just a few seconds no exception is thrown and the data is stored successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Add an [@javax.ejb.Asynchronous](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ejb/Asynchronous.html) annotation to your `storeData()` method:

```
...
@Asynchronous
public void storeData() {
    ...
```

This will allow your application to start up properly while `storeData()` does its thing in a background thread.

You might want to move your CalculatorService calls into that method as well...